# Using libcurl "multi" interface for single file download - C++

Tags: c++, file, http, asynchronous, libcurl

I am creating a C++ dll and I need to make a single non-blocking http request. What I mean is that at a certain point in the dll, I need to kick off a download of a file in the background, but resume the program after the single download is kicked off.

I am currently using libcurl as my http client. I read that the multi-interface (https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html) will give me non-blocking functionality, but all of the examples I see are for making multiple http requests simultaneously, and waiting for all of them to finish w/a while loop for example. Am I able to use this interface to make a single http request, and resume my program while it downloads? And if so, can it fire a callback upon completion? Or do I have to continually check the handle to see if the download is complete?

Example of single request with libcurl multi interface:

```
int main() {

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

    // init easy curl session
    auto curl_easy = curl_easy_init();

    // set url
    auto url = "https://[foo].exe";
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_easy, CURLOPT_URL, url);

    // set curl to write file to directory
    auto path = "C:\\foo\\app.exe";
    auto filePtr = std::fopen(path, "wb");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_easy, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writeFile);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_easy, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, filePtr);

    // init multi curl session
    auto multi_handle = curl_multi_init();

    // add easy handle to multi handle
    curl_multi_add_handle(multi_handle, curl_easy);

    auto res = curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &running);

    auto running = 0;
    while (running) {
        res = curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &running);
    }
```

I'd like to not do the `while (running)` loop and go do other things in main while the file downloads. I may be misunderstanding the "non-blocking" nature of curl_multi_perform(). Is it non-blocking only in the sense that many requests can happen simultaneously? If so, I don't think using it to make a single request gets me anything I wouldn't have with curl_easy_perform. Apologies if this is veering outside of stack overflow, I don't want a libcurl tutorial. But should I instead be using something like a blocking libcurl call (curl_easy_perform) inside of std::async()?

Comment: `libcurl` provides callback functionality but it's up to you to synchronize threads. One way would be to notify that it's done via a condition variable in the callback function - but it's hard to say more without  knowledge about the setup. Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks, I edited my original post with an example of my use. Aside from the callback, I'm unclear on whether using the multi interface is exclusively for making multiple requests asynchronously, or if I can make a single request that is asynchronous with the rest of my program. With multi, it seems like I have to keep calling `curl_multi_perform` in a while loop until the response is finished downloading.

Comment: No, you don't need the `multi` interface for making multiple requests asynchronously. To be honest, I've never used the multi interface myself. Just thread it and throw out requests as you please. As long you present the result in an orderly fashion (synchronized) you're all good.

Comment: Ah, good to know, thank you @TedLyngmo! I was definitely confused. There's even a multi-threaded example on the libcurl site that I missed: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multithread.html

Comment: It may be but have in mind that the multi-threaded part is there to support C programmers too. If you as a C++ programmer find better means - you should go that way.